# hand draw arrow in pdf-tools

Tags: pdf-tools

I like using pdf-tools to annotate a pdf file. **Is there a way of hand-drawing an arrow (by dragging the mouse) in pdf-tools?** It would help a lot in annotating pdf files. Even a template arrow (instead of hand drawn) would be good. As a possible solution I noticed that forward search from latex to pdf-tools does put a temporary arrow in the pdf file. Maybe a similar mechanism can be used to add an annotation arrow?

Comment: With customize variable `pdf-annot-default-annotation-properties` you can change the icon of text annotations. There is no arrow within the default list, though. But maybe you can figure out yourself how to add one.

Answer (score 0):

There is [pymupdf-mode](https://github.com/dalanicolai/pymupdf-mode.el) now. It is hacky but does a nice job and is very customizable with only very basic elisp and some custom python pymupdf commands from the excellent [pymupdf documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-add-and-modify-annotations).

Comment: I used the command 'pip3 install pymupdf' - as mentioned in the documentation. This installed stuff in my ./local/lib/python3.8/site-packages directory.  But when I open a pdf file in pdf-tools and then type M-x pymupdf-mode;  emacs does not recognize this mode. It says no match. Please let me know how to install this in emacs. It sounds like a very useful addition to pdftools. There must be something missing in the instructions for installation into emacs.

Comment: @Vikram Great that you tried `pymupdf-mode`. So this mode simply opens a python shell in a comint buffer and then it sends the necessary python commands to that buffer, while interpreting their outputs. Different GNU/linux distributions use different ways to implement python, and Emacs needs to be configured accordingly. I think if python is configured correctly then the instructions should work (not sure though). For sure I would like to know/(help you to) find out why it does not work there. But for that you should open an issue [here](https://github.com/dalanicolai/pymupdf-mode.el/issues).